# convert bat to sh

Tags: windows, ubuntu, scripting

I am totally new to scripting in linux...so i want to port some simple window bat files to ubuntu.

First file is easy

```
  setenv.bat
    set ANT_HOME=c:\ant\apache-ant-1.7.1
    set JAVA_HOME=c:\java
```

in linux i did this and it seems ok

```
  setenv.sh
      #!/bin/bash
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/
    ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
    echo $JAVA_HOME
    echo $ANT_HOME
```

but now i want to port this bat file:
  startserver.bat

```
call ../config/setenv

call %ANT_HOME%/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_db
call %ANT_HOME%/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_server


pause
```

but i have no clue how can i do this in linux call ../config/setenv

thank you for any help , direction given.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be:

`#!/bin/sh

source ../config/setenv.sh

${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_db

${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_server`

`source` will make the variables which are set in setenv.sh available to your current script.
`${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant` will execute the ant binary.
The `pause` will just wait so that the cmd.exe window doesn't close, I'd suggest not to port that.

Anyway, this is all really basic stuff, take a look at some basic shell scripting tutorials like:
https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/unixscripting/unixscripting.html

Comment: `.//usr/share/ant/bin/ant` is a nonsense path, there shouldn't be a `./` before the variable

Answer (score 2):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cd /path/to/working/directory
 source ../config/setenv
 $ANT_HOME/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_db
 $ANT_HOME/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_server
 sleep 10
```

Once you're in a script you can call scripts directly - however the problem with this is that all the calls are relative.  That's fine if you can be sure of that - so what you can do is add a command to make sure of that - cd /path/to/working/directory

Comment: Does this actually work? the script doesn't `export` the variables and you're not sourcing the script

Comment: Correct I should have sourced setenv

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pull in those environment variables use the keyword "source" (aka '.') instead of call

for starting the programs you don't need to prefix "call"

additionally variables are referenced by $variablename instead of %variablename%

Answer (score 1):

And another example:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/
export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant

$ANT_HOME/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_db
$ANT_HOME/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_server
```